# MVC - view click event is not fired in jquery

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, view

I have the below simple code, where I need to trigger an alert when click on the button. But the event is not triggered.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Dashboard";
}
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $("#btnclickhere").click(function (e) {
        alert(1);
        e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
        return false;        // This should not be used unless you do not want
        // any click events registering inside the div
    });
</script>
<h2>Dashboard</h2>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <td>
                <input type="text" id="textname" name="txtname" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="textpassword" name="textpassword" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btnclickhere" name="btnclickhere" value="ClickHere" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can someone help me to figure out the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is loaded before the html tags, so there is nothing called #btnclickhere at the time you ask jQuery to register the click handler. You should wrap your jquery code in a $(document).ready(function(){/*your code here*/}); event handler to ensure the DOM is fully populated before querying.